# Generic root of a number in c

Tags: c

Generic root of a number is defined as the sum of digits of a number until we get a single digit.
For example:

Generic root of 456: 4 + 5 + 6 = 15 since 15 is two digit numbers so 1 + 5 = 6

So, generic root of 456 = 6

I solved this problem by recursively adding the digits of the number until a single digit number is obtained and the program worked fine. I searched the web and found a very small solution for it which i was unable to understand:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{   int n,x;
    printf("Enter no");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Generic root: %d",(x=n%9)?x:9);
    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to understand how the ternary operator is working here!? How is it calculating the Generic root of a number

Comment: Or it could be defined as n mod 9. (the ternary operator fixes the case when n % 9 == 0)

Comment: means (x=n%9) != 0 ? x : 9

Comment: I think OP already figured out what `(x=n%9)?x:9` means in C. OP is probably looking how this line is calculating the root, in other words OP is looking for the proof of this theorem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A number *n* modulus 9 returns either its root or 0, in which case the root is 9.

1. Calculate n % 9 to get the root
2. If the result is 0, then the root is 9

So `(x=n%9)?x:9` means that if n mod 9 is zero, assign 9.

You can also achieve this without the ternary operator:

```
x = 1+((n-1)%9)
```

The modulus 9 trick is called the [*congruence formula*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root#Congruence_formula).

Comment: That's a trick we were thought in Elementary school to know if a number is divisible by 9.

Comment: BTW the formula `1+((n-1)%9)` gives the right answer even for `n = 0`, while the hack `(x=n%9)?x:9` is incorrect in that case

Answer (score 7):

It's a mathematical trick: the "generic root" of a decimal number is the same as the original number itself modulo 9.  The only problem is if the number is actually a multiple of 9, the C expression `n % 9` will evaluate to zero.

So now let's unpack the ternary:

```
 x = n % 9;
 y = ((x != 0) ? x : 9);
```

Thus if `x` is zero, we get `y=9`, otherwise we  get `y=x`.  Combined with the original mathematical trick, this is what we want.

**The maths**:

This is interesting too: but I won't go into it -- the trick is to prove that all powers of 10 are congruent to 1 modulo 9.

Comment: Basically, since 10**n == 1 mod 9, then each digit in a decimal number just contributes its own value to the mod-9 version.

Comment: For the input being `0`, there should be a special case as well, as otherwise the result is wrong.

Comment: @glglgl This should all work fine if the original input is zero.  In fact 0 is a sort of multiple of 9, in the sense that `0 == 0%9`.

Answer (score 3):

The explanation of the trick in mathematical sense is in the properties of modular arithmetic:

```
a number, say 456 == 4*100 + 5*10 + 6

OTOH  (a+b) mod N == ((a mod N) + (b mod N)) mod N    (1)
AND   (a*b) mod N == ((a mod N) * (b mod N)) mod N    (2)
```

From that it follows, that

```
456 mod 9 ==((4 mod 9)*(100 mod 9) + 
             (5 mod 9)*(10 mod 9) +
             (6 mod 9)*(1 mod 9)) mod 9
```

Substituting the formula (2) to the weights (1 mod 9), (10 mod 9), (10^n mod 9), one gets that each digit only contributes it's own weight to the intermediate sum. That sum (modulo 9) can in return be evaluated iteratively until there's only one digit and where the digit 0 is treated separately. That's also what the ternary operation in the code fragment is for.

Answer (score 0):

The division criteria for division with 9 is that the sum of the digits must be divisible by 9. Doing this recursively, you get the result that a number divisible by 9 has a generic root of 9.

By doing the modulo operation you compute how far you are from a multiple of 9, this distance being also the generic root of the number. If you take a piece of paper and write the generic roots in order, you will see that they increase by 1 each number, and after 9 there comes 1.

There is also a special case you have to consider, 0. Who is divisible by 9 but doesn't have a generic root of 9 ( it is the only number with a generic root of 0 ).

Answer (score 0):

Guys I've a solution who are finding (x=n%9)?x:9 difficult to understand. Check the if conditions carefully. NOTE: the number we enter must be greater than 10.

```
int main()
{

int n;

printf("Enter number...");
scanf("%d",&n);
if(n%9==9)
    {
    printf("The generic root of the number is : 9");

    }
else if(n%9!=0)
{
    printf("The generic root of the number is : %d",n%9);
}
return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In Easily the mathematical trick is:

```
15 % 9 = 6-- 1+5=6
14 % 9 = 5-- 1+4=5
18 % 9 = 0-- 1+8=9
```

In this concept it works

```
if x != 0 it return x value
if x == 9 it returns the value 9 
printf("Generic root: %d",(x=num%9)?x:9);
```